# Linq to SQL with Mono: Can't connect to my sqlite database

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, mono

I would like to access an sqlite database from mono:
The database is stored in the file "languages.sqlite" and contains the table "spanish-german".

- I installed the monodevelop database addin
- I created a database connection - with the IDE tool
- Then tested this connection - with the IDE tool query database.

  select * from "spanish-german"

> "hablar| sprechen"
>
> "hacer | machen,tun"

The table has two columns, one with the spanish word and one with the german translation

- I created a LINQ class - with the IDE. The output looks good. A class for the database and another for the table was created.

Now I need to connect to the database in my code. This should be rather straightforward, but I can't get it to work. Here's my code:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=languages.sqlite";

DataContext dataContext = new DataContext (connectionString);
Table<Spanish_German> words = dataContext.GetTable<Spanish_German> ();

var query =from word in words select word;

foreach (var word in query)
    Console.WriteLine (word.Spanish);
```

This compiles just fine, but when run, the code halts at the final print statement.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()  "filename unknown"

Apparently the filename was incorrect. The database is stored in a folder databases.
I tried the following connectionstrings:

- "languages.sqlite"
- "databases/languages.sqlite"
- "languages"
- "databases/languages"
- "Data Source=languages.sqlite"
- "Data Source=databases/languages.sqlite"
- "Data Source =languages"
- "Data Source = databases/languages"

And then found out that MS has a custom format for these strings and "Data Source" should be called "Addr". So now I'm using
 - "Addr=languages.sqlite"

And am getting a different exception:

> Mono.Data.Tds.TdsInternalException has been thrown. Server closed the connection.

What is that ? How can I fix it ?

**UPDATE:**

I changed the build option for the database to "content" and had it copied to the output directory. Then I added "Version=3;" to the connectionString. And finally I changed the dataContext to use sqLite.

With all three changes the program works, if one of them is left out, it doesn't.

Thank you very much. If one of you would create an answer out of his comment, I would accept it.

Comment: String DB_CONNECTION_STRING = "Data Source=./MyDictionaryDB.sqlite;Version=3;New=False;Compress=False;";  // where the database and the EXE are in the same folder. or try to use : String DB_CONNECTION_STRING = "URI=file:./MyDictionaryDB.sqlite;Version=3;New=False;Compress=False;";

Comment: but why you have got  'SqlClient.SqlConnection' since you are using Sqlite? see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12648217/992406

Comment: that would be stealing your good hard earned rep ... post it yourself and mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the build option for the database to "content" and had it copied to the output directory. Then I added "Version=3;" to the connectionString. And finally I changed the dataContext to use sqLite.

Now the program runs fine.